# "Rotation-Rig" for 2D

Tags: animation, rigging, grease-pencil, 2d

I am looking for a very specific information. With my production company, I am currently working on the development of a 2D animation show. For several reasons, including economic and political, We have mentioned Blender in potential software. We already use Blender for compositing and 3D animation and know that some studios use it in 2D, on productions of different sizes. We have specific rig needs. I come to my question: Have you heard of an equivalent of Harmony's "rotating-rig" in Blender. This feature allows you to rig a 2D character from different angles. We are looking for an equivalent whether it is a way of organizing collections for example, Add-ons, or other DIY.

Bonjour, Je suis à la recherche d'une information très spécifique. Avec ma société de production, Je travaille actuellement sur le développement d'une série d’animation 2D. Pour plusieurs raisons, notamment économiques et politiques, Nous avons mentionnés Blender dans les logiciels potentiels. Nous utilisons déjà Blender pour du compositing et de l'animation 3D et savons que certains studios l'utilisent en 2D, sur des productions de différentes envergures. Nous avons des besoin spécifiques en terme de rig. J'en arrive à ma question: Auriez vous entendu parler d'un équivalent du "rotating-rig" de Harmony dans Blender. Cette fonctionnalité permet de rigger un personnage 2D sous différents angles. Nous cherchons un équivalent qu'il s'agisse d'une façon d'organiser les collections par exemple, d'Add-ons, ou autre bricolage.

<3

Vidéo: Learn What a Rotating Rig is with Harmony Premium
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPn9nel9SsE